# Change event fired twice on changing radio group manually with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When selecting "A&L" in the select, the radio group is hidden and its value is set to "n".
I try to trigger the change event so that the "Hello"-div disappears too, but it doesn't work correctly - on debugging I noticed that the change event is executed twice - the first time correctly and then again with the value "j".

What's my mistake?

Here's the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/95Lxroqy/

After I looked through some other questions it seemed to me that `.val(['n']).change();` (line 24) should have worked -
but it seems like I'm still missing something.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message");
var button = $("#place");
var langs = $("#langs");
var trans = $("#trans");
var radioGroup = $("input[type=radio][name=translate]");
var div = $("#dynamic");

radioGroup.change(function() {
    if (this.value === 'n') {
       div.hide();
    }
    else if (this.value === 'j') {
        div.show();
    }
});

// handle click and add class
button.change(function(event){
 var al = button.val() === "al";
 if(al){
  langs.show();
  trans.hide();
  radioGroup.val(['n']).change();
  }else{
  trans.show();
  langs.hide();
  }
}).change();
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
   <select id="place">
  <option value="in">Internal</option>
  <option value="al">A&L</option>
</select> 
   <select id="langs">
  <option value="volvo">German</option>
  <option value="saab">English</option>
</select> 
<fieldset id="trans">
    <input type="radio" id="n" name="translate" value="n">
    <label for="n"> Nein</label> 
    <input type="radio" id="j" name="translate" value="j">
    <label for="j"> Ja</label>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="dynamic">
  Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` get/set the value of the element. Your code matches all the options exist in the collection variable, it does not match the specific element you are looking for. You can target the parent element from which you can find the the specific element by using attribute selector.

Try

```
radioGroup.parent().find('[value=n]').change();
```

**Update:** The more feasible solution is using the `filter()`

```
radioGroup.filter('[value=n]').change();
```

Comment: so you mean,val() returned both "n" and "j" element, then first the change() was triggered on "n" and then on "j" and that was the problem? Thanks, your line of code worked :)

Comment: @Cold_Class, actually `val()` is used to get/set the value  (it does not filter the element by matching the value), your code returns both the the element and fails to trigger the event:)

Comment: "fails to trigger the event" is not entirely correct though - when I put an `alert` inside the radioGroup change function I can see that it is triggered twice.

Comment: @Cold_Class, I mean fails to trigger the event on the specific element (you are looking for).

Comment: oh, I and noticed `radioGroup.filter('[value=n]').change();` seems to work too

Comment: @Cold_Class, I agree that you would be the more feasible solution in this case.